# dreamhost VPS returns a lot of blank pages

Tags: 6, wsod

After upgraded from shared hosting to VPS (for more memory), my site returns a lot of blank pages, for example:

- plain `/update.php` is OK, but returns blank page after clicking `Continue` and `Update`
- plain `/admin/reports/status` is ok, but `/admin/reports/updates/check?destination=admin%2Freports%2Fstatus` returns blank space

php `memory_limit` is now 512M.

Any dreamhost user shares some experience?

Comment: what PHP/apache logs says?

Comment: no error from apache error.log, where can I see drupal php error log?

Comment: You can see PHP errors log in drupal it self, watchdog log...

Answer (score 1):

I would check PHP error reporting on the server : usually, WSOD are caused by hidden PHP errors. A value of `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` is usually fine, at least for development.

Comment: blank pages, no error/warning on browser.

Comment: Precisely. Did you check PHP error reporting ?